# Why does default python version change every time I create env with conda?

Tags: python, anaconda, conda, environment

I use Anaconda on windows10.
Every time I create a new environment with `conda` command without specifying a particular `python` version, it just seems to install different versions of python.
Why does this happen? How does `conda create` command decide which version of `python` to fetch?

Example:
`conda create -n env_name1` -> `activate env_name1` -> `python --version` -> **python 3.9.1**
`conda create -n env_name2` -> `activate env_name2` -> `python --version` -> **python 3.8.3**

Comment: Perhaps you've ended up with a different condarc file in that environment.

Comment: Aren't you requesting at the same time installation of some packages, e.g. `conda create -n name package1 package2`? Or exactly as you put it in the question? Clarifying since the latter would be really weird. It should be deterministic.

Comment: @LukaszTracewski Exactly as I put it in the question, but now it seems to only install python 3.8.3 whenever I create a new env. It definitely happened yesterday though, when I conda created -n env_name, it installed python 3.9.1. 
How does conda decide which python to install? Can it be set in config?

Comment: `conda create -n env_name1` alone doesn't install anything, so you're likely just picking up Python from elsewhere on PATH. Generally, one will almost always have a better experience with Conda by specifying all known requirements at environment creation. So try `conda create -n env_name1 python=3.8` (or whatever version you actually require), plus any packages.

Comment: @merv thanks, that clarified things for me. As you said, `conda create -n env_name1` doesn't install `python`, `python --version` inside the env just refers to python located in `base` env. I also realised that there are multiple `python.exe` with different versions installed in `C:\Users\anaconda3\pkgs` dir (I don't know why) , and one of which is `python3.9.1` so it must've referred to this one for some reason.

Comment: @koyamashinji the `pkgs` dir is not the installation directory for packages, its only a cache

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have deactivated env_name1 before creating the new env_name2, because you may be using different configuration files (.condarc) and channels.

Try creating all environments from the base one.